# Django HTML não atualiza no browser

Tags: html, python, django

Eu acredito que a estrutura do meu projeto seja um tanto complexa. Como é um framework, não o iniciei do zero.

Meu problema ocorre quando tento fazer alterações no conteúdo de texto de arquivos HTML e inicio o navegador. Alguns arquivos `.html` aceitam essas alterações, enquanto outros não. Os arquivos HTML que aceitam essas alterações estão no diretório *test_project*, o mesmo diretório em que executo `python manage.py runserver`. Eu diria que é obrigatório iniciar o servidor a partir deste diretório. Se eu tentar o diretório principal, que inclui o `manage.py` primário, recebo o erro `no such table: django_session`. Por sua vez, os arquivos HTML que não aceitam as alterações estão no diretório *qa*.

O que devo fazer para atualizar os arquivos HTML em ambos diretórios, test_project e qa?

---

Espero ter colocado informações suficientes. Obrigado!

```
.
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── CONTRIBUTING.rst
├── HISTORY.rst
├── LICENSE.md
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── base.rst
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── installation.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── settings.rst
├── manage.py
├── qa
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── mixins.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── signals.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── utils.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20160412_1336.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20160414_1413.py
│   │   ├── 0004_answer_updated.py
│   │   ├── 0005_auto_20160519_1057.py
│   │   ├── 0006_question_total_points.py
│   │   ├── 0007_answer_total_points.py
│   │   ├── 0008_auto_20160719_0729.py
│   │   ├── 0009_auto_20160919_1528.py
│   │   ├── 0010_auto_20160919_2033.py
│   │   ├── 0011_question_slug.py
│   │   ├── 0012_remove_question_views.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0002_auto_20160412_1336.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0003_auto_20160414_1413.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0004_answer_updated.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0005_auto_20160519_1057.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0006_question_total_points.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0007_answer_total_points.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0008_auto_20160719_0729.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0009_auto_20160919_1528.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0010_auto_20160919_2033.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0011_question_slug.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── 0012_remove_question_views.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── mixins.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── qa.css
│   │   └── qa
│   │       ├── icon.ico
│   │       ├── qa_index.jpeg
│   │       ├── qa_page.jpeg
│   │       ├── question.jpg
│   │       └── user.png
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 403.html
│   │   └── qa
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── create_answer.html
│   │       ├── create_comment.html
│   │       ├── create_question.html
│   │       ├── detail_question.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── profile.html
│   │       ├── update_answer.html
│   │       └── update_question.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── runtests.py
├── setup.py
├── test_project
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── register.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── simpleqa
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── test_mixins.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── test_models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── test_views.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── test_mixins.py
│   ├── test_models.py
│   └── test_views.py
└── tree.txt

20 directories, 124 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez, você precise fazer um apontamento correto no seus settings na TAG TEMPLATES segue a minha como exemplo:

```
> TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates") 
>      TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
>         'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
>         'APP_DIRS': True,
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'context_processors': [
>                 'django.template.context_processors.media',
>                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
>                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
>                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
>                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
>             ],
>         },
>     }, ]
```